# Need checkbox with an x in it

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox

I need a form with a bunch of checkboxes which would become a box with x in it if clicked. I have managed to create such a checkbox (it's a custom checkbox), but the x is not coming when I click it. Instead when I try to give a background color if checked, it's working properly. Here is my code

CSS :

.checkbox-row {
font-size:6.0pt;line-height:115%;font-family:
"Times New Roman",serif;color:#1F1F1F;
display:inline-block;

```
}

 input[type="checkbox"] {
      display: none;
    }

    .custom-checkbox {
      width: 7px;
height:7px;
      border: 0.5px solid #000;
      cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 14px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

display:inline-block;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .custom-checkbox {
     content: 'X' !important;
      font-size: 14px !important;
      color: black;

      text-align: center;
      line-height: 7px;
    }
```

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div class="checkbox-row">

                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" th:checked="${flag}"/> <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
                    Rural 
                </label>

                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" th:checked="${customer.getActive()}"/> <span class="custom-checkbox">  </span>
Semi urban
                </label>

                 <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" th:checked="${flag ? false: true}"/> <span class="custom-checkbox">  </span>
 Urban
                </label>

<br>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Try to explain simply what you want to try to do. Do you want to create a custom checkbox that does not look like the default checkbox? Note that input elements are replaced elements and as such neither pseudo-elements nor are they able to contain pseudo-elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style a checkbox using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: You are looking for this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56411758/11293647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `content` property – when used on an element – does not work as your code suggests you think it does. Check the [MDN docs about the content property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) for a full explanation. In short, you cannot put text into an element using the `content` property. You can however put text into a pseudo element using the content property.

If you change your selector `input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .custom-checkbox` to `input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .custom-checkbox::before` you will see the "X" you want to appear. Of course you may need to edit your styling to get it to look right but you'll get your "X".